# How preload initial data from API redux?

Tags: reactjs, redux

I'm new in react (redux).
Server send me this info (initial):

```
{boards:[objects],lists:[objects],tasks:[objects]}
```

Also, I have 3 reducers: boards,lists,tasks in my combineReducers.
But i don't know how preload initial data from my web server?
I want send initialData with this data from server when app is running.
Thanks.

Comment: in the `componentDidMount` or `componentWillMount` you can **dispatch an action** to fetch the data from the server

Comment: Thanks. But what about combineReducers? each reducer work with it branch. Boards - with "boards"  branch of Store, lists - with "lists" branch. How do I can update "All Store" from server data? Dispatch an action for every branch (boards,lists,tasks)?

Comment: you 're right, combineReducer enables to have one reducer for each part of your store, one reducer for boards part, one reducer for lists part, otherwise you would have had one **big** reducer for the whole store which would become pretty unmaintanable as soon as the store get bigger and bigger

Comment: as a result you can dispatch three actions, fetchBoards, fetchLists, fetchTasks

Comment: Thanks. My actions: in componentWillMount i dispatch an action - OK. The next step: in action i run axios and get data from server. Then, I dispatch action with type "FETCH_ALL". And in every reducers I catch the "FETCH_ALL" and return the branch for this reducer. For example, action.data.boards, action.data.lists, action.data.tasks. My way is right?

Comment: yes you have two solutions, dispatch only one action FETCH_ALL like you said, or dispatch three actions FETCH_LISTS, FETCH_BOARDS... it depends if you want to reload them later independently

Comment: Thanks a lot. My a ask one question yet?)) My app is use boards,lists,tasks (aka trello, but more difficult). Which way is better for this: 1. Load all data (boards,lists,tasks) and showing it as a filter(). 2. Load data by after click object. (click board  - load lists, click list - load tasks).

Comment: depends of the amount of data to load, if you have a lot of lists and tasks, then I think it's better to load data by clicking on the element, If all the data is not really big you can fetch all these data on init, then it will give the user a really fast UX

Comment: Thanks. Yes, data is not a big. Also, I think to load all data at once is a good idea. Because this tasks is located in a different areas (lists area, inbox area, important area and etc). Of course I may to load it from API (for each area), but this tasks have to included in Store. Simple - load it and filtering in a it smart component. I'm right?)

Comment: I don't know what you mean `by filtering in a it smart component`...

Comment: `Filtering in a it smart component` - in component from it "connect" method we have  "state". I take it current state and filtering it by params (tasks). For example `tasks:state.tasks.filter(task => task.id == 44)`.

Comment: ok I think it's the good way

Comment: Thanks a lot. Your advices helped me!

Answer (score 0):

You can initialize the store with an initial state. 
http://redux.js.org/docs/api/createStore.html